# Types of unaccusative verbs

Tags: grammaticality

I'm trying to gauge whether there is a pattern in (1-3); specifically, whether verbs of (dis)appearance and verbs of (dis)assembling pattern differently in these structures. Which of these are acceptable and which awkward-sounding?

> (1a) There came out (of) her room a strange man
>
> (1b) There came off (of) her finger a big ring
>
> (2a) Sarah saw a strange man come out (of) her room
>
> (2b) Sarah saw a big ring come off (of) her finger
>
> (3a) Which man did Sarah see come out (of) her room
>
> (3b) Which ring did Sarah see come off (of) her finger

Comment: I don't think that's gonna be a distinction to rely on. (1a-b) are equally starred to me -- can't use _there_-insertion with _come_ when the un-_there_-inserted sentences are perfectly grammatical and far easier to parse. (2a-b) and (3a-b) are each normal and grammatical.

Comment: While '(1a) There came out of her room a strange man' sounds like it would work in one of Grimm's stories, (1b) 'There came off  her finger a big ring' almost sounds like the ring is a volitional agent.

Comment: _Out of her room there came a strange man/odor/gasp/light/*idea._